# How do I access UrlMapping variables in grails from a filter?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 2.1.5 and the Spring Security Core plugin.
I've overridden the WebSecurityExpressionRoot to add 2 signatures of a hasPermission method to the web expression paradigm.
This method delegates to classes by name in the applicationContext calling them with the request as an argument and an arbitrary string to provide further details if any are ever required.

In my delegate class I need to be able to access the parameters to assess whether or not the user may access the requested resource and this is fine but the request does not yet contain the variables defined from the UrlMappings.

I have tried acquiring the grailsUrlMappingsHolder from the applicationContext but when I call it's match method with a valid uri I get nothing.

I'm running out of time and may have to parse the request.getRequestURI() myself to try to infer the id if no request parameters are valid but this will not get urls mapped where the id is not last.

I really hate to re-invent the wheel here and I hate to miss out on using the UrlMappings to their fullest potential but the variables they define (in my circumstance) aren't available until I'm in the controller.

Comment: If I've undesrstood you right, you need access to params, hidden in url. If you define url like /some/url/$myParam, you should have myParam in params object

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what I do in `AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition` - there's a bit of setup that you need to do: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/web/access/intercept/AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.java